# facebook c# sdk multiquery example?

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk

I am using the facebook c# sdk for windows phone and cannot find any examples of how to use the multiquery functionality with one query being used as a parameter or source for the other.

Below is an example of what I'm trying to do, but this doesn't seem to work.  Any help is appreciated.

string query0 = string.Format("SELECT aid, size, name, cover_pid, description, owner, modified_major, created, size FROM album WHERE owner = " + u.UID.ToString());

string query1 = string.Format("SELECT pid, aid, src FROM photo WHERE pid IN (SELECT cover_pid From #query0 )");
            string[] queries = new string[2];
            queries[0] = query0;
            queries[1] = query1;
            _fbClient.QueryAsync(queries);

Answer (score 0):

look at the nuget package Facebook.Sample

```
Install-Package Facebook.Sample
```

There are samples on how to use multiquery.

Comment: I installed Facebook.Sample and still do not see an example of how to create a multiquery that uses 1 fql's results as the parameter in a 2nd query. The example I found only shows how to run 2 fql's: var query1 = "SELECT uid FROM user WHERE uid=me()"; var query2 = "SELECT profile_url FROM user WHERE uid=me()";

Comment: With the facebook toolkit I could do somehting like this:  string query0 = "SELECT aid, size, name, cover_pid FROM album WHERE owner = me()";                                                      string query1 = "SELECT pid, aid, src FROM photo WHERE pid IN (SELECT cover_pid From #query0 )"; 
                                                                     Can you show me an example of how to do this with the c#sdk?  The Facebook.Sample example just runs 2 seperate queries, but I need something that essentially is like doing a table join.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a nested multi-query where the results of one function act as the input for the second... The only issue with the Facebook C# SDK is that it doesn't give you control over what those queries are named - here's a working example:

```
        dynamic checkins =
            client.Query(
                            "SELECT uid FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())", //Stand-alone query
                            "SELECT author_uid, timestamp, coords, tagged_uids, page_id, checkin_id, message FROM checkin WHERE author_uid IN (SELECT uid FROM #query0)", //Depends on the results of the first query (get friend IDs)
                            "SELECT name, page_id, pic, pic_large, page_url, type, website FROM page WHERE page_id IN (SELECT page_id FROM #query1)" //Depends on the results of the GetCheckinLocationDetailsQuery
                         );
```

Your queries will be named #query0, #query1, and so forth. You can refernece those via the FacebookClient.Query method

Answer (score 0):

Starting from facebook c# sdk v6, there are two ways to execute fql multi-query

```
var fb = new FacebookClient("access_token");
dynamic result = fb.Get("fql", new
    {
        q = new[]
                {
                    "SELECT uid from user where uid=me()",
                    "SELECT name FROM user WHERE uid=me()"
                }
    });
```

named fql multi-query

```
var fb = new FacebookClient("access_token");
dynamic result = fb.Get("fql",
    new
        {
            q = new
            {
                id = "SELECT uid from user where uid=me()",
                name = "SELECT name FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid FROM #id)",
            }
        });
```